# Create contacts from attached vCard?

Tags: gmail, contacts

Using GMail, is there a way to automatically add contacts from a vCard that has been emailed to me.  I know that I can download it to my local system and import it from there, but I'm looking for a quicker, one-step, method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, GMail does not support this feature.

There are several [posts](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=741c6561de881d9f&hl=en) on help forums discussing this.  I also tried copying the link to the attachment and using the url in Contacts when it asked for a file.  It was a long shot, and it didn't work.

Comment: Any specific reason/reference to explain why?

Comment: Good point, I should have included this information in my answer.  I've edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link to the support forum.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easyer way! if you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your Outlook contacts synced using one of the provided applications to that service. They will then sync their server with Google and you get all of your contacts :)

So you can one-click to import the vCard into Outlook (or another app) and have them synced to MemoToo within a few minutes and into your Google contacts a few minutes after that.

This service also supports syncing your contacts from Facebook, LinkedIn and most other contact, calander online stores so you have a single point of truth that can sync with your phone, outlook and other services.

I like it as it supports pictures as well and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).